# Problems with repair /dev/disk0 (internal, physical). Invalid request (-69886)

Tags: hard-drive, mac, operating-systems, repair

How can I fix the error 69886. Also i got the error 22 in this context. Check the image at this post for the terminal screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please don't delete questions then repost. Use the dit button to add requested information.

Comment: From your previous post, we're still missing a lot of information - "What OS precisely? Why are you running as root? What's the full output & what does diskutil list say? Post as text, not as images. [select the pasted text & hit Ctrl/K to format it for here]"

Comment: yes of course, but the image didn't reupload while editing

Comment: it didn't need to re-upload, it was already here. We don't want a picture anyway, we want text.